# Как если на экране есть есть кнопка в названии переменной в которой она находится есть "save_people", то при нажатии на неё начиналась функция save_p?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Я создаю динамически создаю groupbox'ы и в них кнопки имеющие одинаковое имя, но при этом как я понял каждый следуйщий groupbox и его название, например 1-ый groupbox назывался groupBox_1, то следующий будет называться groupBox_2. Также я думаю и со всеми в него входящими виджетами. Как мне при нажатии на кнопку (в любом groupbox) я знал имя переменной в которая её содержит?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте objectName вместо названия переменной

Название переменной узнать будет тяжело, может, даже невозможно.

Намного проще задавать каждой кнопке атрибут `.objectName`.

```
...
self.deleten_2.setObjectName('deleted_2')
...
```

А потом - получать `.objectName`:

```
...
self.sender().objectName
...
```